# unable to view the bufferedimage

Tags: java, swing

I am new to swing. I was trying the game tutorial by wilchit sombat on making of packman.  I cannot view the `BufferedImage`. Here is the code which overrides some methods from the game engine.

```
package game.packman;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.Game.Engine.Game;
import org.Game.Engine.GameApplication;

public class PackMan extends Game {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GameApplication.start(new PackMan());
    }

    BufferedImage packman;

    public PackMan() {
        title = "PACKMAN";
        width = height = 400;
        try {
            packman = ImageIO.read(new File("images/pacmanimg.xcf"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void init() {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(packman, 100, 100, null);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Image I/O` has built-in support for `GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP`. Image I/O is also extensible so that developers or administrators can "plug-in" support for additional formats. For example, plug-ins for `TIFF` and `JPEG 2000` are separately available.

So, it seems that `XCF`: native image format of the `GIMP` image-editing program, is not supported by `ImageIO`.

**Reference:**

1. [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: i also tried loading a png file but i am still facing the same problem

Comment: Check that your `images` folder is at the same location of the `PackMan` class file location.

Comment: I have never had such issue, unless the `PNG` is corrupted! Otherwise `ImageIo` would throw an exception if the file wasn't found

Comment: Well that's the issue as i cannot see the image in the window and the program runs fine without any exception or error

Answer (score 0):

Check size of the image `packman` after loaing

```
packman = ImageIO.read(new File("images/pacmanimg.xcf"));
```

It's 0 width/height if the image is not loaded.

Anyway it's better to place the image in your classpath and use getResourceAsStream() to load it through ImageIO. In opposite case when you pack your code in a jar you need to resolve working with files and relative paths problem.

Comment: `It's 0 width/height if the image`- That is only if the file doesn't have actual format we are trying to, or more correctly corrupted which i already have mentioned in the comment. But `ImageIO` doesn't even support `xcf` image type file processing as the documentation says